# center current wordpress horizontal submenu & sub-submenu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently working on a wordpress-based website.

I need to make the current-page horizontal submenus and sub-submenus be aligned to the center of the screen.

you can see a current-submenu here: http://suisse.coopi.org/en/support-us/volunteering/

and a current sub-submenu here: http://suisse.coopi.org/en/about/organization/regulation/

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: has few error, see the console. Also are you hardcoding the exist menu?

Comment: Yes I am hardcoding the existing menu, I'm modifying the customizr wordpress theme as a child theme.
I already tried with automatic margins and with transform: translateX(-50%); but the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is not centered either. It's just an illusion. You have the aligned to the left matching the "offset" of its parent.

I think you can get it by simply adding:

`transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: to be clear I want to center them to the page and not to the parent menu voice.